# Vehicle spins upon collision in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm developing a car game for Gear VR in unity. I'm currently facing a problem where the car spins upon collision. So far I've tried freezing the position and changing the angular drag to a larger value. Freezing problem doesn't solve the issue since the car stop turning completely on turns. Can anybody please advise any other solution.
I'm using unity standard asset for the car physics.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the angularVelocity?

Comment: Where can I find angular velocity option??

Comment: Its on the Rigidbody, accessed through a script.  also have you tried using physic's materials with your car as well>?

Comment: I would suggest not setting velocities manually if you want the physics to remain realistic. The car spins because a vehicle that collide would spin. Is the mass of your car somewhat correct regarding the forces you apply on it?

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud really depends on what he is trying to achieve, but I have never seen a car "spin" when it collides with things, I have seen it bounce to the side, be pushed to the side, go over objects it's collided with, and have the back lift off of the ground but never just "spin".  Which is why my second comment also mentions Physic's Materials as that would prevent him from having to adjust the angular velocity directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue via scripting. On collision with wall, I just set the angular velocity of the car to Vector3.zero.